# Getting error while configuring dsc

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-dsc

Configuring DC using dsC getting below this error

A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: New Domain Safe Mode Administrator Password (A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: New Domain Safe Mode Administrator Password)

Comment: Which DSC Resource are you using.

Comment: xActivedirectory